# Debugging a library with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, frameworks, shared-libraries

I have a more general question on working with libraries on with Xcode when building iPhone apps. I've created a framework from a project I've been working on to use some parts of it in other apps. That works pretty good, so far. But I have no idea how to debug into the files included in the included framework.

I hope to get some kind of 'best practice' on that.

Thanks a lot
–f

Answer (score 6):

There have been a lot of discussions of how best to reuse code with static libraries.  I've settled on the method described [here](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/) by Clint Harris (which I think is what Shawn is suggesting as well).  Creating a project dependency in this way automatically compiles the library for your project's target (simulator/device, debug/release) so you don't need four different copies of the compiled library sitting around.  It also lets you step into the library source when debugging, as you want.  Finally, updates to the library are included in any of the linked projects the next time those projects are compiled (so you don't have to recompile and redistribute the library binary to those projects yourself).

Comment: Hey Tim! Thanks for that hint. That integration works great. But I'm still not able to debug my library using breakpoints. Is there some kind of additional step I have to make?

Comment: I just played around with this and found the following: By default, when I set a breakpoint in my library project it does not actually break in any linked projects, as you observe.  However, I then right-click on the breakpoint, select "Edit Breakpoint" and in the Breakpoints window I drag that new breakpoint over to the name of my linked project in the "Groups & Files" section.  Or you can drag it to "Global Breakpoints," but then it will break in any linked project.  Once I have changed that setting the breakpoint works in the linked project.  Does this work for you?

Comment: This works but there was one gotcha: if you have both projects open, the subproject won't appear as a full project in the parent project. So close out the subproject before adding it. (XCode complains that it would cause a data integrity problem to have the same project open in two places.)

Answer (score 4):

Generally, I'll include the Xcode project for the library as an external project dependency of the main application's project. The advantage of project dependencies, is that you can add a build phase that builds a fresh copy of your library along with the main project, and of course it will let you set breakpoints in the library's code.