# Xcode's feature similar to Visual Studio's add reference?

Tags: visual-studio, xcode

I asked about debugging dylib in Xcode in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720098/how-to-debug-dylib-with-xcode). For Visual Studio, I can use the 'Add New Reference' in Property pages to assign a dynamic library project from the project that uses the library. And, I can put all the project in one single solution file, and make the project as 'Startup Project'. I just set breakpoints and run to debug the dynamic library.

Can Xcode do the similar/same thing?

- Can Xcode have two or more projects in one something like VS2010's solution file?
- Does Xcode provide something like referencing project to debug dynamic library?

Answer (score 0):

> Can Xcode have two or more projects in one something like VS2010's solution file?

You can include an Xcode project in another Xcode project. Just use the Add Existing File action to add it. Then you can reference any of the included project's build products.

Comment: Could you elaborate the 'reference any of the products'? I could add the library Xcode project, but I don't get how to have the reference of the library from the enclosing Xcode project.

Comment: @prosseek: If you include another Xcode project, you can set any of its products as a dependency, just as if it existed in the parent project.