# Deugging subprojects in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, subproject

I have a Xcode project which contains multiple subprojects (3rd party libraries). These subprojects are compiled into static libraries during build generation. The problem which I am facing is the breakpoints wont work inside those subprojects. I am also unable to symbolicate the crash logs . Whenever a crash occurs in those modules it just says __lldb_unnamed__function. Is this because of some setting which I use in the main project? How can I enable debugging in subprojects?

Comment: Your question really is how do you enable debugging in Static Libraries and Frameworks, right?

Comment: @Popeye : Yes. Also I tried atos commmands get the crash logs. That didn't work very well.

Comment: Here are a few links that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654493/how-can-i-debug-in-a-framework-in-xcode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025732/debugging-a-library-with-xcode https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=debugging+a+framework+in+xcode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=qjbGU4HSM8WK4Aac4YCYDw I've struggled with this in the past also, but I can't remember what I did.